# Accessing public inherited Template data members

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

I require some clarification on the question why do we need the scope resolution operator or `this` pointer to access publicly inherited members from a template base class.
As I understand it is for adding clarity but then how does `this` add any further clarity than just point that it is a member of the class.

To make my question clearer I have added some code.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <class T, class A>
class mypair {
        public:
         T a, b;
  public:
    mypair (T first, T second)
      {a=first; b=second;}

        virtual void printA() 
        {   
        cout<<"A"<<a<<endl;
        cout<<"B"<<b<<endl;
        }   
};







template <class T, class A>
class next: mypair<T,A>
{
public:

        next (T first, T second) : mypair<T,A>(first, second)
        {   
        }   

        void printA() 
        {   
        cout<<"A:"<<mypair<T,A>::a<<endl; // this->a; also works 
        cout<<"B:"<<mypair<T,A>::b<<endl; // this-b;  also works
        }   

};


int main () {
  next<double,float>  newobject(100.25, 75.77);
  newobject.printA();
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
A:100.25
B:75.77
```

If i remove the scope(or this operator) then the out of scope error comes.
But why do we need a scope for publicly inherited members.

Some thoughts on this would be great.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Refer to [Name lookup - Using the GNU Compiler Collection (GCC)](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Name-lookup.html)

By adding explicit prefix `mypair<T, A>`, or `this->`, you make `printA` template argument dependent. Then the definitions will be resolved during template instantiation stage.

Comment: Interesting Read

So is this a special case with templates only?

Comment: Only in functions in template class.